# How to replace the authorize method in ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, ember-testing

I'm trying to refactor my Ember acceptance tests to not use the [deprecated](https://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html#method_authorize) `authorize` method, as it is throwing a warning:

```
The `authorize` method should be overridden in your application adapter
```

I checked the [docs](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#deprecation-of-authorizers), and numberous other sources, but they don't actually explain *how* to migrate my code. Here's what I've got at the moment:

```js
// projectname/app/pods/login/controller.js (excerpt)
export default Controller.extend({
    session: service(),
    sessionToken: null,

    onSuccess: function(res) {
    res = res.response;
        this.set('sessionToken', res.session);
        if (res.state === "authenticated") {
            document.cookie = "token="+res.session+";path=/;";
            var authOptions = {
                success: true,
                data : {
                    session : res.session,
                }
            };
            this.get('session').authenticate("authenticator:company", authOptions);
        }
    }
});
```

And this must be the part that I'm meant to get rid of:

```js
// project/app/adapters/application.js (excerpt)
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
    authorize(xhr) { // This is deprecated! I should remove it
        let sessionToken = this.get('session.data.authenticated.session');
        if (sessionToken && !isEmpty(sessionToken)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Token " + sessionToken);
        }
    },
});
```

And here is my test:

```js
import { test, module } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL, find, click, fillIn } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { authenticateSession} from 'ember-simple-auth/test-support';

module('moduleName', function(hooks) {
    setupApplicationTest(hooks);

    test('moduleName', async function(assert) {
        // await authenticateSession(this.application); // Never works
        // await authenticateSession(); // Never works
        await authenticateSession({
            authenticator: "authenticator:company"
        }); // Works slightly more?
        await visit('/my/other/page');
        await assert.equal(currentURL(), '/my/other/page');
    });
});
```

REMOVING the `authorize` method and attempting either of the commented out methods yields:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The `authorize` method should be overridden in your application adapter. It should accept a single argument, the request object.
```

If I use the `authenticator` block as an arg, then regardless of the presence of the `authorize` method, I simply get:

```
    actual: >
        /login
    expected: >
        /my/other/page
```

Which, I assume, is because it did not login.

Leaving the `authorize` method there, and trying the commented methods yields:

```
Error: Browser timeout exceeded: 10s
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#deprecation-of-authorizers) you linked above: To replace authorizers in an application, simply get the session data from the session service and inject it where needed.

Since you need the session data in your `Authorization` header, a possible solution for your use case may look like this:

```js
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
    headers: computed('session.data.authenticated.session', function() {
      const headers = {};
      let sessionToken = this.get('session.data.authenticated.session');
      if (sessionToken && !isEmpty(sessionToken)) {
        headers['Authorization'] = "Token " + sessionToken;
      }

      return headers;
    })
});
```

This should allow you to dynamically set the `Authorization` header, without doing so via the `authorize` method.

Comment: Doing this simply results in an error: `The 'authorize' method should be overridden in your application adapter. It should accept a single argument, the request object.`. How can I get rid of a deprecation if doing so changes it into an error?

Comment: @Addison I think the missing piece here is that in the linked docs, they're using `ember-fetch` as well, and the adapter extends `AdapterFetch` in addition to `DataAdapterMixin`.

Answer (score 0):

[Ember Simple Auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth), has an excellent community and quickly created a [guide on how to upgrade to v3](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/upgrade-to-v3.md).

The latest version fixes this problem completely - If anyone is having this problem, upgrading to `2.1.1` should allow you to use the new format in your `application.js`:

```
headers: computed('session.data.authenticated.session', function() {
    let headers = {};
    let sessionToken = this.get('session.data.authenticated.session');
    if (sessionToken && !isEmpty(sessionToken)) {
        headers['Authorization'] = "Token " + sessionToken;
    }
    return headers;
}),
```

This problem was only present in `2.1.0`.